# What is the meaning of "a" and "z" in capacitor value - Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: capacitor, modeling, cadence, units, virtuoso

What is the meaning of "a" and "z" in capacitor value? Here is the image:

[image]

I think "a" is angstrom,  But I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume they are SI prefixes. In which case,

- `a` would be `atto` or \$10^{-18}\$
- `z` would be `zepto` or \$10^{-21}\$

Note also that some values have `p` which would be `pico` (\$10^{-12}\$).